# What does this statement do in octave? X = [ones(20,1) (exp(1) + exp(2) * (0.1:0.1:2))'];

Tags: octave

```
X = [ones(20,1) (exp(1) + exp(2) * (0.1:0.1:2))'];        
X = X(:,1)
```

What will be value of the vector X ?

Comment: What result did you observe when you ran the code ?

Comment: sorry for asking this stupid question. I was facing some problems installing octave on mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first column of `X` is defined by `ones(20,1)` which will generate a `20 x 1` vector with ones.

`X = 
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1
     1`

The second column of `X` is defined by `exp(1) + exp(2) * (0.1:0.1:2))`

`(0.1:0.1:2)` will generate a `1 x 20` vector which is turned into a `20 x 1` vector by transposing this vector with `'`:

`0.1000
    0.2000
    0.3000
    0.4000
    0.5000
    0.6000
    0.7000
    0.8000
    0.9000
    1.0000
    1.1000
    1.2000
    1.3000
    1.4000
    1.5000
    1.6000
    1.7000
    1.8000
    1.9000
    2.0000`

The result is multiplied with the sum of `exp(1) + exp(2)`:

`3.4572
    4.1961
    4.9350
    5.6739
    6.4128
    7.1517
    7.8906
    8.6295
    9.3684
   10.1073
   10.8462
   11.5851
   12.3241
   13.0630
   13.8019
   14.5408
   15.2797
   16.0186
   16.7575
   17.4964`

After this `X` will look like this:

`X =
    1.0000    3.4572
    1.0000    4.1961
    1.0000    4.9350
    1.0000    5.6739
    1.0000    6.4128
    1.0000    7.1517
    1.0000    7.8906
    1.0000    8.6295
    1.0000    9.3684
    1.0000   10.1073
    1.0000   10.8462
    1.0000   11.5851
    1.0000   12.3241
    1.0000   13.0630
    1.0000   13.8019
    1.0000   14.5408
    1.0000   15.2797
    1.0000   16.0186
    1.0000   16.7575
    1.0000   17.4964`

`X = X(:,1)` will select all rows from the first column of `X`.

Thus `X` will be a `20 x 1` vector with ones.